# How to configure spellcheck functionality in Solr?

Tags: apache, solr, solrcloud

I want to implement spellcheck functionality in Apache Solr-6.6.4, but am not able to do so. My program is not suggesting me the correct word that should be used (in Solr query).

My collection name is *employee*. I want to implement spellcheck on field name *jobTitleName*.

I have referred to the following link:
http://akashmusings.blogspot.com/2016/03/spell-check-with-solr.html

I am using following configurations.

**schema.xml**

```xml
<uniqueKey>userId</uniqueKey>

 <field name="userId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
 <field name="jobTitleName" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="firstName" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="lastName" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="preferredFullName" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="employeeCode" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="region" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="phoneNumber" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="emailAddress" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
 <field name="_version_" type="tver" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
 <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
 <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" />
  <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true"/> 
  <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" docValues="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="tdates" class="solr.TrieDateField" docValues="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="tlongs" class="solr.TrieLongField" docValues="true" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="tver" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
  <fieldType name="tdoubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" docValues="true" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" docValues="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />
```

**solrconfig.xml (spellcheck)**

```xml
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">jobTitleName</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
    </lst>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="field">lowerfilt</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

**solrconfig.xml (update)**

```xml
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">firstName</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>    
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">   
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>   
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">jobTitleName</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
    </lst>    
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="field">lowerfilt</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
       </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

**Requirement**
I want that when user enters the wrong jobTitleName, Solr should produce the correct recommendation using spellcheck.

e.g. If the user enters Developr as jobTitleName, Solr should produce recommendation as Developer to the user using spellcheck.

Comment: Is there any entries with `jobTitleName` that is _just_ `developer`? Do you get any fields in your response that indicates that the spellchecker was invoked? (i.e. entries referring to spelling)